# Solidity - How do I write a function that sets an address to a struct?

Tags: struct, mapping, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to create a function that can set an address to a struct so that I can enter that address and get the struct data returned to me.
I.e. 0x876... returns name "John", balance "99"

I get an error message on 'getInfoByWallet[_wall] = teamWallets;' that says

"from solidity:
mapping.sol:22:34: TypeError: Type type(struct Mapping.teamWallets storage pointer) is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Mapping.teamWallets storage ref.
getInfoByWallet[_wall] = teamWallets;"

Im pretty confused and not really sure what to do. Any help is much appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Mapping {

    struct teamWallets {
        string name;
        uint256 balance;
    }

    string name = "";
    uint256 balance = 0;
    teamWallets[] public _teamWallets;
    
    mapping(address => teamWallets) public getInfoByWallet;

    function addteamData(string memory _name, uint256 _balance) public {
        _teamWallets.push(teamWallets(_name, _balance));
    }

    function setInfo(address _wall, teamWallets memory) public {
        getInfoByWallet[_wall] = teamWallets;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use struct with mapping in solidity then you have to follow this approach that I have mention in below.

here your teamWallets is struct. then you have used it in mapping getInfoByWallet.

Now, when you have to set the data in mapping like

```
struct teamWallets {
    string name;
    uint256 balance;
}

mapping(address => teamWallets) public getInfoByWallet;


function setInfo(address _wall, string memory _name, uint256 _balance) public {
    getInfoByWallet[_wall].name=_name;        
    getInfoByWallet[_wall].balance=_balance;
}
```

So, this is the right approach to store a data in struct with mapping in solidity. I hope, now you clear with this error.